# Text Document splitting to Pages in Qt

Tags: qt, text

I want to write Book Reader Program in Qt C++, like a Book Read Mode in MS Word.

See the image

[image]

And I need to show text in pages, no any scrollbars,

So which way can I deal with text pages in Qt? The QTextEdit control has no page splitting as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [QTextDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html). It supports pagination.

You can set the desired [size of page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#pageSize-prop) and `QTextDocument` will process the text implicitly to calculate [number of pages](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#pageCount).

Rendering of text can be done by [QTextDocument::drawContents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#drawContents) where you limit rendering only to specific page of document by providing it's relative `QRectF` coordinates.